# Decrypt a password

Tags: hash, passwords, ascii, md5, decode

How do I decrypt a password given this :
Password:

Code:
01001101 01111010 01100111 00110001 01011010 01101010 01000001 00110101 01001101 01000111 01001001 00110000 01001111 01010111 01010001 01110111 01011001 01111010 01000101 01111010 01001101 01010100 01010101 00110000 01001101 01000100 01000110 01101100 01001110 00110010 01010101 01111000 01011010 01010111 01001110 01101101 01011010 01010100 01000001 01111001 01001101 00110010 01001101 00111101

password: ascii, base //////// md5 Happy (+1 x2)

Ive been stumped for two days trying to figure this out :(

Answer (score 0):

Wow, binary. Hexadecimal is generally used to display binary data.

The data looks like characters and Base64 at that based on the trailing "=" byte (00111101 is hex 3D which is "=").

In short MD5 is a non-reversible one-way hash function. The only way is brute-force, that is trying passwords until you find a match or give-up.